ActiveMQ Artemis is not removing page files even if the messages are processed
We are facing this issue in one of our production environments with ActiveMQ Artemis 2.21.0. ActiveMQ Artemis is not removing the paging files even if the messages are processed. The page files accumulate which is causing a great impact on the size. The page files are removed when the broker is restarted.
Configuration used:
<max-size-bytes>104857600</max-size-bytes>
<page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
<address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>

Is there any way to know what operations are being performed with the page file(s) (e.g. enabling of logs, etc.)?

@JustinBertram since it is a production environment, we are struggling to do any modification in it. I will update you once we have any findings around it.

I strongly recommend you upgrade to the latest release of ActiveMQ Artemis. Version 2.21.0 was released in March 2022 (over two years ago now). Hundreds of bugs have been fixed since then, not least with paging. You may find that your issue has already been resolved. However, if it hasn't then being on the latest is still desirable since it will prove that the issue hasn't already been resolved and will provide a solid basis for additional investigation.
If you want more details about paging operations at runtime you can turn on TRACE logging for the following categories:

org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.impl.PagingManagerImpl
org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.impl.PagingStoreImpl

